# unique values in array count

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array like the following

```
var data = [
            ["1"," 101_30.1.101_34","0.0200112629","mm/s","[OK]"],
            ["1"," 101_30.1.101_35","0.0146548533","mm/s","[OK]"],
            ["1"," 101_30.1.101_45","0.0146548533","mm/s","[OK]"],
            ["1"," 101_42.2.101_43","0.0101406257","mm/s","[OK]"],
            ["2"," 102_17.3.102_38","5.1719756","mm/s","[WA]"],
            ["2"," 102_17.3.102_39","3.5886707","mm/s","[WA]"],
            ["2"," 102_17.3.102_44","9.4615074E-4","mm/s","[OK]"],
            ["2"," 102_40.4.102_41","4.8159785","mm/s","[OK]"],
            ["3"," 204_15","3.8374166","mA","[OK]"],
            ["4"," 501_11","1027.5156","RPM","[WA]"]
           ]
```

What im trying to do is find how many unique array there are. Example 1=4,2=4,3=1,4=1

The data is coming from a database, so the number of arrays can always change.

Here is a simple jsfiddle of what im talking about [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mariob316/xDfay/)

Comment: Are you looking to just find duplicates of the first value of the array?

Comment: ...and your question is?

Comment: Just iterate over the array and count the occurrences of the first element of each element.

Comment: Yes, basically im looking for duplicates of the first value. I dont want to remove them, i just need to count them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var count = {};
$.each(data, function(){
    var num = this[0]; // Get number
    count[num] = count[num]+1 || 1; // Increment counter for each value
});
console.log(count); // {1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 1, 4: 1}
```

Comment: @RocketHazmat I tried this but for some reason it's only counting until 9? ex: `{1: 84, 2: 97, 3: 31, 4: 57, 5: 28, 6: 21, 7: 28, 8: 25, 9: 18}` Also, what could I add so that duplicates are deleted?

Comment: @Patrick: This question is almost 3 years old.  Why not ask a new one?  If you don't want to, at least tell me what you are trying to do.  What do you mean by "only counting until 9"?